# Internet Explorer line 1 char 1 code 0 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

I'm using jQuery+drupal and some jQuery plugins. All is ok with
Firefox. But in IE's i'm receiving problem like this.

Line: 1
Char: 1
Error: object expected
URL: http://businessway.am

I have included .js files. How to know where is the problem? In which
file? Line 1? Which file?

If you can please check site which I gave before.

Comment: I get the following error message:
 artNoStyleAdding is not defined
http://businessway.am/
line: 84

Comment: Billy what debugger are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could get this type of errors in case the url of a `<script src="...url..."></script>` does not return javascript, but some other content (html)

I checked the page, but all scripts with src actually do seem to return javascript. With a bit more digging, it seems that this eval code triggers the error message:

```
artNoStyleAdding(document)
```

It looks like it is coming from this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">if (Drupal.jsEnabled) {$(document).ready(function(){             window.setTimeout("artNoStyleAdding(document)", 2000);});}</script>
```

That's the last but one script in the head of the document.

Apperantly you forgot to declare and code the `artNoStyleAdding` function, whatever it is supposed to do.

Comment: All files exist, and are JavaScript files.

Comment: Thank you. it's fixed :) how you debug javascript?

Comment: I use firefox and firebug if I can. If I must, I use visual studio for IE (the built-in thingie in IE8 has silently stopped working for some reason, and I didnt like it anyway). You do need to enable debugging, do: Menu / Tools / Internet Options and uncheck  " disable script debugging" , check "display a notification about every script error"

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this error come up in IE7 when you have a javascript object with an extra comma on the end.

Example:

```
  var something = {
    "one": ["a"],
    "two": ["b"],
  };
```

Should be:

```
  var something = {
    "one": ["a"],
    "two": ["b"]
  };
```

IE8, Chrome, and Firefox don't seem to mind it though.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same error, only in IE, when putting comments in a certain spot:

```
function initMyUI() {
    $("#myId") // Don't put comments here.
        .delegate("#btnMyButton", "click", _clickDoSomeThings);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of IE you'll want to break out the development tools available. You can use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html), built in dev tools in IE8 or go the old standby and use [Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/).

Comment: I'm using IE8 and DebugBar. All looks ok to me! I'm not expert in JavaScript :))

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed in IE7 and IE8, but IE6 give's same error.

**Updated:** Fixed. Sorry :)